# Openid account validation without password reset

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

I enabled Openid, and installed the [OpenID selector](https://drupal.org/project/openid_selector) module.  When a user logs in via openid, they have to validate their email, and the way to do so is by drupal sending them a one-time login link to reset their password.  Is there any other way to validate the email address?  Sending a password reset link is confusing for users.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your users to be able to setup their own password, check out [LoginToboggan](https://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan). It adds password fields on the front-end user registration page and optionally links non-verified accounts to a "temporary" role on the site, if you want to limit their behavior/actions until they confirm the email.
It also features a lot of other goodies and tweaks, which make the registration/login process much easier.

Another option is [Email Verification](https://drupal.org/project/email_verify), which checks if the domain or host of the email address exist, and tries to validate the account by sending `HELO/MAIL FROM/RCPT TO` to the host's SMTP server.

Comment: Thanks for the module recommendations, but I guess I should have been more clear on my question.  What I really want to know if there's another way to validate a user account, without sending the user to the password reset page (e.g. send to a user confirmation page).  Sending them to a password change page might be a little confusing.